# Change boolean variable if TRY code is executed correctly

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I change the value of a boolean variable if the ***try*** code is executed correctly?
This is my code, I try to get the address of the current position of the user, but, for example, if the user is in the ocean, when i try to put the address in a textview, the application crash.
I want to create an ***if*** structure that checks if the boolean variable is true and then puts the address in a text view.

```
Geocoder geocoder;
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

textView.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
```

Comment: You can set address in try block after getting an address , in that way it won't set address if any catched exception occur, 

Also please post the exception here

Comment: I need the boolean variable also for other uses, then I need to write the code like in the question. I can't post the exception because the program crash if the current position haven't got an address

Comment: In that case you can declare it outside of try catch block with default value(true) and change it to false in catch block and use it later for condition. Still i don't understand the issue. why you are not able to use `boolean`. Also please post any error log here even if you don't get address.

Comment: Can you write an example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

        boolean ok = false;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            ok = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(ok){
           textView.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
        }
```